# Cost Function Confusion for Ordinary Least Squares estimation in Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

Just wanted to check that my current understanding of linear regression is correct and address some confusion I have with the cost function used in OLS estimation. My current understanding is this:

Given a data set:

$\{y_i, x_{i1}, x_{i2}, ... ,x_{ip}\}_{i=1}^{N}$

The Multiple Linear Regression Model that most accurately describes the relationship between dependent variable $y$ and independent variables $x_1, x_2, ... , x_p$ is the linear function:

$y = \beta_0x_0 + \beta_1x_1 + ... + \beta_px_p = \sum_{j=0}^p\beta_j(x_j)$

such that $\forall y_i$ (where $y_i = \beta_0x_{i0} + \beta_1x_{i1} + ... + \beta_px_{ip} + \epsilon_i$)

the sum of squared residuals: $\sum_{i}^{N}\epsilon^2 = \sum_{i}^{N}(y_i - (\beta_0x_{i0} + ... + \beta_px_{ip}))^2$ is minimized.

This all comes from the following sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Matrix/vector_formulation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Simple_and_multiple_linear_regression

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares

My confusion comes from other sources I have looked at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148912/feature-scaling-normalization-in-multiple-regression-analysis-with-normal-equa

https://machinelearningmedium.com/2017/08/11/cost-function-of-linear-regression/

which say that the Multiple Linear Regression Model that most accurately describes the relationship between $y$ and $x_1, x_2, ... x_p$ is the same linear function I originally defined above but that the coefficients $\beta_0, \beta_1, ..., \beta_p$ for it are those which minimize the cost function:

$\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_i - (\beta_0x_{i0}+ \beta_1x_{i1} + ... + \beta_px_{ip}))^2$

So my question is this: Is my current understanding correct? and which of these cost functions should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned - all of these functions are equivalent to each other up to a multiplication by some constant. Moreover, you can view the sum of squares as slightly more algebraic approach as 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1x_i)^2 = \|\mathrm{y} - X\beta\|^2,
$$ 
which is equivalent to minimizing the Euclidean norm itself. That is, finding an orthogonal projection.  While,
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1x_i)^2 =
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - g(x_i))^2,  
$$
where $g(x_i)$ is the mean of $y_i$.
This approach may be referred as minimizing the empirical mean squared error (MSE) which is a more statistical POV.

Comment: I can understand how $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1x_i)^2 = \Vert y - X\beta \Vert ^2$ but what I do not understand is the geometric interpretation: "finding an orthogonal projection". What is this projection orthogonal to exactly? Is it something like this: https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/projections.html ?

Comment: @bmanicus131  See here for example: https://people.eecs.ku.edu/~jhuan/EECS940_S12/slides/linearRegression.pdf
The projected $y$ is orthogonal to the errors $y - \hat{y}$. Namely, $y$ is projected onto the column space of $X$, where $\hat{\beta}$s are the coordinates of $\hat{y}$ in $C(X)$.

Answer (score 2):

Either cost function is fine. Since they are just constant multiples of each other, minimising one is equivalent to minimising the other (will result in same fitted $\beta$ coefficients).